# How can I run 2 watch commands simultaneously for coffeescript?

Tags: shell-script, coffeescript

I'd like to run the following commands in parallel with 1 shell script.

```
coffee -wc lib/
coffee -wcb public/
```

Currently, I have to press ctrl+c to cancel out of the first one before the second line can execute.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run both simultaneously.

```
   # coffee -wc lib/ && coffee -wcb public/
```

**UPDATE**:  As per Dennis and Neurolysis's comment, I'm changing the answer to use an &.  Although both commands are similar, the && operator will cause the 2nd command to be run only after the first is completed.

```
 ## print 'program1', wait 4 seconds, print 'program2'
 # echo 'program1';sleep 4 && echo 'program2'

 ## print 'program1' and sleep, but also simulatneously print 'program2'
 # echo 'program1';sleep 4 & echo 'program2'
```

Thus, the technically correct answer is:

```
 # coffee -wc lib/ & coffee -wcb public/
```

Comment: Unless coffee executes much differently than I'm used to, won't this merely do 'execute on success' rather than 'execute simultaneously'?

Comment: I should be a single ampersand.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to be able to help and also learn something new at the same time.